# Use NeoSWSerial instead of SoftwareSerial with Adafruit Fingerprint Library

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm using the FPM10A fingerprint sensor together with the Adafruit Fingerprint Library. I also have a GPS and Bluetooth module on the board already (connected to an Arduino UNO) and I'm using the neoSWserial library to communicate with them. I would like to use neoSWserial to communicate with the fingerprint sensor.

I've replaced all the instances of SoftwareSerial with NeoSWSerial in the respective .h and .cpp files but now the program says

```
'Did not find fingerprint sensor'
```

For completeness here's the sketch, .h and .cpp file:

```
/*************************************************** 
  This is an example sketch for our optical Fingerprint sensor

  Designed specifically to work with the Adafruit BMP085 Breakout 
  ----> http://www.adafruit.com/products/751

  These displays use TTL Serial to communicate, 2 pins are required to 
  interface
  Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code, 
  please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing 
  products from Adafruit!

  Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada for Adafruit Industries.  
  BSD license, all text above must be included in any redistribution
 ****************************************************/


#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>

// On Leonardo/Micro or others with hardware serial, use those! #0 is green wire, #1 is white
// uncomment this line:
// #define mySerial Serial1

// For UNO and others without hardware serial, we must use software serial...
// pin #2 is IN from sensor (GREEN wire)
// pin #3 is OUT from arduino  (WHITE wire)
// comment these two lines if using hardware serial
NeoSWSerial mySerial(12, 13);

Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&mySerial);

void setup()  
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);  // For Yun/Leo/Micro/Zero/...
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("\n\nAdafruit finger detect test");

  // set the data rate for the sensor serial port
  finger.begin(57600);
  delay(5);
  if (finger.verifyPassword()) {
    Serial.println("Found fingerprint sensor!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Did not find fingerprint sensor :(");
    while (1) { delay(1); }
  }

  finger.getTemplateCount();
  Serial.print("Sensor contains "); Serial.print(finger.templateCount); Serial.println(" templates");
  Serial.println("Waiting for valid finger...");
}

void loop()                     // run over and over again
{
  getFingerprintIDez();
  delay(50);            //don't ned to run this at full speed.
}

uint8_t getFingerprintID() {
  uint8_t p = finger.getImage();
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
      Serial.println("No finger detected");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      Serial.println("Imaging error");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }

  // OK success!

  p = finger.image2Tz();
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }

  // OK converted!
  p = finger.fingerFastSearch();
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Found a print match!");
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_NOTFOUND) {
    Serial.println("Did not find a match");
    return p;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }   

  // found a match!
  Serial.print("Found ID #"); Serial.print(finger.fingerID); 
  Serial.print(" with confidence of "); Serial.println(finger.confidence); 

  return finger.fingerID;
}

// returns -1 if failed, otherwise returns ID #
int getFingerprintIDez() {
  uint8_t p = finger.getImage();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;

  p = finger.image2Tz();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;

  p = finger.fingerFastSearch();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;

  // found a match!
  Serial.print("Found ID #"); Serial.print(finger.fingerID); 
  Serial.print(" with confidence of "); Serial.println(finger.confidence);
  return finger.fingerID; 
}
```

The header file:

```
#ifndef ADAFRUIT_FINGERPRINT_H
#define ADAFRUIT_FINGERPRINT_H

/***************************************************
  This is a library for our optical Fingerprint sensor

  Designed specifically to work with the Adafruit Fingerprint sensor
  ----> http://www.adafruit.com/products/751

  These displays use TTL Serial to communicate, 2 pins are required to
  interface
  Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code,
  please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing
  products from Adafruit!

  Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada for Adafruit Industries.
  BSD license, all text above must be included in any redistribution
 ****************************************************/

#include "Arduino.h"
#if defined(__AVR__) || defined(ESP8266)
#include <NeoSWSerial.h>
#elif defined(FREEDOM_E300_HIFIVE1)
#include <NeoSWSerial.h>
#define NeoSWSerial NeoSWSerial
#endif

#define FINGERPRINT_OK 0x00
#define FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR 0x01
#define FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER 0x02
#define FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL 0x03
#define FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS 0x06
#define FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL 0x07
#define FINGERPRINT_NOMATCH 0x08
#define FINGERPRINT_NOTFOUND 0x09
#define FINGERPRINT_ENROLLMISMATCH 0x0A
#define FINGERPRINT_BADLOCATION 0x0B
#define FINGERPRINT_DBRANGEFAIL 0x0C
#define FINGERPRINT_UPLOADFEATUREFAIL 0x0D
#define FINGERPRINT_PACKETRESPONSEFAIL 0x0E
#define FINGERPRINT_UPLOADFAIL 0x0F
#define FINGERPRINT_DELETEFAIL 0x10
#define FINGERPRINT_DBCLEARFAIL 0x11
#define FINGERPRINT_PASSFAIL 0x13
#define FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE 0x15
#define FINGERPRINT_FLASHERR 0x18
#define FINGERPRINT_INVALIDREG 0x1A
#define FINGERPRINT_ADDRCODE 0x20
#define FINGERPRINT_PASSVERIFY 0x21

#define FINGERPRINT_STARTCODE 0xEF01

#define FINGERPRINT_COMMANDPACKET 0x1
#define FINGERPRINT_DATAPACKET 0x2
#define FINGERPRINT_ACKPACKET 0x7
#define FINGERPRINT_ENDDATAPACKET 0x8

#define FINGERPRINT_TIMEOUT 0xFF
#define FINGERPRINT_BADPACKET 0xFE

#define FINGERPRINT_GETIMAGE 0x01
#define FINGERPRINT_IMAGE2TZ 0x02
#define FINGERPRINT_REGMODEL 0x05
#define FINGERPRINT_STORE 0x06
#define FINGERPRINT_LOAD 0x07
#define FINGERPRINT_UPLOAD 0x08
#define FINGERPRINT_DELETE 0x0C
#define FINGERPRINT_EMPTY 0x0D
#define FINGERPRINT_SETPASSWORD 0x12
#define FINGERPRINT_VERIFYPASSWORD 0x13
#define FINGERPRINT_HISPEEDSEARCH 0x1B
#define FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATECOUNT 0x1D

//#define FINGERPRINT_DEBUG

#define DEFAULTTIMEOUT 1000 ///< UART reading timeout in milliseconds

///! Helper class to craft UART packets
struct Adafruit_Fingerprint_Packet {

  /**************************************************************************/
  /*!
      @brief   Create a new UART-borne packet
      @param   type Command, data, ack type packet
      @param   length Size of payload
      @param   data Pointer to bytes of size length we will memcopy into the
     internal buffer
  */
  /**************************************************************************/

  Adafruit_Fingerprint_Packet(uint8_t type, uint16_t length, uint8_t *data) {
    this->start_code = FINGERPRINT_STARTCODE;
    this->type = type;
    this->length = length;
    address[0] = 0xFF;
    address[1] = 0xFF;
    address[2] = 0xFF;
    address[3] = 0xFF;
    if (length < 64)
      memcpy(this->data, data, length);
    else
      memcpy(this->data, data, 64);
  }
  uint16_t start_code; ///< "Wakeup" code for packet detection
  uint8_t address[4];  ///< 32-bit Fingerprint sensor address
  uint8_t type;        ///< Type of packet
  uint16_t length;     ///< Length of packet
  uint8_t data[64];    ///< The raw buffer for packet payload
};

///! Helper class to communicate with and keep state for fingerprint sensors
class Adafruit_Fingerprint {
public:
#if defined(__AVR__) || defined(ESP8266) || defined(FREEDOM_E300_HIFIVE1)
  Adafruit_Fingerprint(NeoSWSerial *ss, uint32_t password = 0x0);
#endif
  Adafruit_Fingerprint(HardwareSerial *hs, uint32_t password = 0x0);

  void begin(uint32_t baud);

  boolean verifyPassword(void);
  uint8_t getImage(void);
  uint8_t image2Tz(uint8_t slot = 1);
  uint8_t createModel(void);

  uint8_t emptyDatabase(void);
  uint8_t storeModel(uint16_t id);
  uint8_t loadModel(uint16_t id);
  uint8_t getModel(void);
  uint8_t deleteModel(uint16_t id);
  uint8_t fingerFastSearch(void);
  uint8_t getTemplateCount(void);
  uint8_t setPassword(uint32_t password);
  void writeStructuredPacket(const Adafruit_Fingerprint_Packet &p);
  uint8_t getStructuredPacket(Adafruit_Fingerprint_Packet *p,
                              uint16_t timeout = DEFAULTTIMEOUT);

  /// The matching location that is set by fingerFastSearch()
  uint16_t fingerID;
  /// The confidence of the fingerFastSearch() match, higher numbers are more
  /// confidents
  uint16_t confidence;
  /// The number of stored templates in the sensor, set by getTemplateCount()
  uint16_t templateCount;

private:
  uint8_t checkPassword(void);
  uint32_t thePassword;
  uint32_t theAddress;
  uint8_t recvPacket[20];

  Stream *mySerial;
#if defined(__AVR__) || defined(ESP8266) || defined(FREEDOM_E300_HIFIVE1)
  NeoSWSerial *swSerial;
#endif
  HardwareSerial *hwSerial;
};

#endif
```

And the .cpp file:

```
/***************************************************
  This is a library for our optical Fingerprint sensor

  Designed specifically to work with the Adafruit Fingerprint sensor
  ----> http://www.adafruit.com/products/751

  These displays use TTL Serial to communicate, 2 pins are required to
  interface
  Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code,
  please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing
  products from Adafruit!

  Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada for Adafruit Industries.
  BSD license, all text above must be included in any redistribution
 ****************************************************/

#include "Adafruit_Fingerprint.h"

//#define FINGERPRINT_DEBUG

#if ARDUINO >= 100
#define SERIAL_WRITE(...) mySerial->write(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define SERIAL_WRITE(...) mySerial->write(__VA_ARGS__, BYTE)
#endif

#define SERIAL_WRITE_U16(v)                                                    \
  SERIAL_WRITE((uint8_t)(v >> 8));                                             \
  SERIAL_WRITE((uint8_t)(v & 0xFF));

#define GET_CMD_PACKET(...)                                                    \
  uint8_t data[] = {__VA_ARGS__};                                              \
  Adafruit_Fingerprint_Packet packet(FINGERPRINT_COMMANDPACKET, sizeof(data),  \
                                     data);                                    \
  writeStructuredPacket(packet);                                               \
  if (getStructuredPacket(&packet) != FINGERPRINT_OK)                          \
    return FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR;                                       \
  if (packet.type != FINGERPRINT_ACKPACKET)                                    \
    return FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR;

#define SEND_CMD_PACKET(...)                                                   \
  GET_CMD_PACKET(__VA_ARGS__);                                                 \
  return packet.data[0];

/***************************************************************************
 PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
 ***************************************************************************/

#if defined(__AVR__) || defined(ESP8266) || defined(FREEDOM_E300_HIFIVE1)
/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Instantiates sensor with Software Serial
    @param  ss Pointer to NeoSWSerial object
    @param  password 32-bit integer password (default is 0)
*/
/**************************************************************************/
Adafruit_Fingerprint::Adafruit_Fingerprint(NeoSWSerial *ss,
                                           uint32_t password) {
  thePassword = password;
  theAddress = 0xFFFFFFFF;

  hwSerial = NULL;
  swSerial = ss;
  mySerial = swSerial;
}
#endif

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Instantiates sensor with Hardware Serial
    @param  hs Pointer to HardwareSerial object
    @param  password 32-bit integer password (default is 0)

*/
/**************************************************************************/
Adafruit_Fingerprint::Adafruit_Fingerprint(HardwareSerial *hs,
                                           uint32_t password) {
  thePassword = password;
  theAddress = 0xFFFFFFFF;

#if defined(__AVR__) || defined(ESP8266) || defined(FREEDOM_E300_HIFIVE1)
  swSerial = NULL;
#endif
  hwSerial = hs;
  mySerial = hwSerial;
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Initializes serial interface and baud rate
    @param  baudrate Sensor's UART baud rate (usually 57600, 9600 or 115200)
*/
/**************************************************************************/
void Adafruit_Fingerprint::begin(uint32_t baudrate) {
  delay(1000); // one second delay to let the sensor 'boot up'

  if (hwSerial)
    hwSerial->begin(baudrate);
#if defined(__AVR__) || defined(ESP8266) || defined(FREEDOM_E300_HIFIVE1)
  if (swSerial)
    swSerial->begin(baudrate);
#endif
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Verifies the sensors' access password (default password is
   0x0000000). A good way to also check if the sensors is active and responding
    @returns True if password is correct
*/
/**************************************************************************/
boolean Adafruit_Fingerprint::verifyPassword(void) {
  return checkPassword() == FINGERPRINT_OK;
}

uint8_t Adafruit_Fingerprint::checkPassword(void) {
  GET_CMD_PACKET(FINGERPRINT_VERIFYPASSWORD, (uint8_t)(thePassword >> 24),
                 (uint8_t)(thePassword >> 16), (uint8_t)(thePassword >> 8),
                 (uint8_t)(thePassword & 0xFF));
  if (packet.data[0] == FINGERPRINT_OK)
    return FINGERPRINT_OK;
  else
    return FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR;
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief   Ask the sensor to take an image of the finger pressed on surface
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_OK</code> on success
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER</code> if no finger detected
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR</code> on communication error
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL</code> on imaging error
*/
/**************************************************************************/
uint8_t Adafruit_Fingerprint::getImage(void) {
  SEND_CMD_PACKET(FINGERPRINT_GETIMAGE);
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief   Ask the sensor to convert image to feature template
    @param slot Location to place feature template (put one in 1 and another in
   2 for verification to create model)
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_OK</code> on success
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS</code> if image is too messy
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR</code> on communication error
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL</code> on failure to identify
   fingerprint features
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE</code> on failure to identify
   fingerprint features
*/
uint8_t Adafruit_Fingerprint::image2Tz(uint8_t slot) {
  SEND_CMD_PACKET(FINGERPRINT_IMAGE2TZ, slot);
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief   Ask the sensor to take two print feature template and create a
   model
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_OK</code> on success
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR</code> on communication error
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_ENROLLMISMATCH</code> on mismatch of fingerprints
*/
uint8_t Adafruit_Fingerprint::createModel(void) {
  SEND_CMD_PACKET(FINGERPRINT_REGMODEL);
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief   Ask the sensor to store the calculated model for later matching
    @param   location The model location #
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_OK</code> on success
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_BADLOCATION</code> if the location is invalid
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_FLASHERR</code> if the model couldn't be written
   to flash memory
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR</code> on communication error
*/
uint8_t Adafruit_Fingerprint::storeModel(uint16_t location) {
  SEND_CMD_PACKET(FINGERPRINT_STORE, 0x01, (uint8_t)(location >> 8),
                  (uint8_t)(location & 0xFF));
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief   Ask the sensor to load a fingerprint model from flash into buffer 1
    @param   location The model location #
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_OK</code> on success
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_BADLOCATION</code> if the location is invalid
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR</code> on communication error
*/
uint8_t Adafruit_Fingerprint::loadModel(uint16_t location) {
  SEND_CMD_PACKET(FINGERPRINT_LOAD, 0x01, (uint8_t)(location >> 8),
                  (uint8_t)(location & 0xFF));
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief   Ask the sensor to transfer 256-byte fingerprint template from the
   buffer to the UART
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_OK</code> on success
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR</code> on communication error
*/
uint8_t Adafruit_Fingerprint::getModel(void) {
  SEND_CMD_PACKET(FINGERPRINT_UPLOAD, 0x01);
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief   Ask the sensor to delete a model in memory
    @param   location The model location #
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_OK</code> on success
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_BADLOCATION</code> if the location is invalid
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_FLASHERR</code> if the model couldn't be written
   to flash memory
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR</code> on communication error
*/
uint8_t Adafruit_Fingerprint::deleteModel(uint16_t location) {
  SEND_CMD_PACKET(FINGERPRINT_DELETE, (uint8_t)(location >> 8),
                  (uint8_t)(location & 0xFF), 0x00, 0x01);
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief   Ask the sensor to delete ALL models in memory
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_OK</code> on success
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_BADLOCATION</code> if the location is invalid
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_FLASHERR</code> if the model couldn't be written
   to flash memory
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR</code> on communication error
*/
uint8_t Adafruit_Fingerprint::emptyDatabase(void) {
  SEND_CMD_PACKET(FINGERPRINT_EMPTY);
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief   Ask the sensor to search the current slot 1 fingerprint features to
   match saved templates. The matching location is stored in <b>fingerID</b> and
   the matching confidence in <b>confidence</b>
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_OK</code> on fingerprint match success
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_NOTFOUND</code> no match made
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR</code> on communication error
*/
/**************************************************************************/
uint8_t Adafruit_Fingerprint::fingerFastSearch(void) {
  // high speed search of slot #1 starting at page 0x0000 and page #0x00A3
  GET_CMD_PACKET(FINGERPRINT_HISPEEDSEARCH, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA3);
  fingerID = 0xFFFF;
  confidence = 0xFFFF;

  fingerID = packet.data[1];
  fingerID <<= 8;
  fingerID |= packet.data[2];

  confidence = packet.data[3];
  confidence <<= 8;
  confidence |= packet.data[4];

  return packet.data[0];
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief   Ask the sensor for the number of templates stored in memory. The
   number is stored in <b>templateCount</b> on success.
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_OK</code> on success
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR</code> on communication error
*/
/**************************************************************************/
uint8_t Adafruit_Fingerprint::getTemplateCount(void) {
  GET_CMD_PACKET(FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATECOUNT);

  templateCount = packet.data[1];
  templateCount <<= 8;
  templateCount |= packet.data[2];

  return packet.data[0];
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief   Set the password on the sensor (future communication will require
   password verification so don't forget it!!!)
    @param   password 32-bit password code
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_OK</code> on success
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR</code> on communication error
*/
/**************************************************************************/
uint8_t Adafruit_Fingerprint::setPassword(uint32_t password) {
  SEND_CMD_PACKET(FINGERPRINT_SETPASSWORD, (password >> 24), (password >> 16),
                  (password >> 8), password);
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief   Helper function to process a packet and send it over UART to the
   sensor
    @param   packet A structure containing the bytes to transmit
*/
/**************************************************************************/

void Adafruit_Fingerprint::writeStructuredPacket(
    const Adafruit_Fingerprint_Packet &packet) {
  SERIAL_WRITE_U16(packet.start_code);
  SERIAL_WRITE(packet.address[0]);
  SERIAL_WRITE(packet.address[1]);
  SERIAL_WRITE(packet.address[2]);
  SERIAL_WRITE(packet.address[3]);
  SERIAL_WRITE(packet.type);

  uint16_t wire_length = packet.length + 2;
  SERIAL_WRITE_U16(wire_length);

  uint16_t sum = ((wire_length) >> 8) + ((wire_length)&0xFF) + packet.type;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < packet.length; i++) {
    SERIAL_WRITE(packet.data[i]);
    sum += packet.data[i];
  }

  SERIAL_WRITE_U16(sum);
  return;
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief   Helper function to receive data over UART from the sensor and
   process it into a packet
    @param   packet A structure containing the bytes received
    @param   timeout how many milliseconds we're willing to wait
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_OK</code> on success
    @returns <code>FINGERPRINT_TIMEOUT</code> or
   <code>FINGERPRINT_BADPACKET</code> on failure
*/
/**************************************************************************/
uint8_t
Adafruit_Fingerprint::getStructuredPacket(Adafruit_Fingerprint_Packet *packet,
                                          uint16_t timeout) {
  uint8_t byte;
  uint16_t idx = 0, timer = 0;

  while (true) {
    while (!mySerial->available()) {
      delay(1);
      timer++;
      if (timer >= timeout) {
#ifdef FINGERPRINT_DEBUG
        Serial.println("Timed out");
#endif
        return FINGERPRINT_TIMEOUT;
      }
    }
    byte = mySerial->read();
#ifdef FINGERPRINT_DEBUG
    Serial.print("<- 0x");
    Serial.println(byte, HEX);
#endif
    switch (idx) {
    case 0:
      if (byte != (FINGERPRINT_STARTCODE >> 8))
        continue;
      packet->start_code = (uint16_t)byte << 8;
      break;
    case 1:
      packet->start_code |= byte;
      if (packet->start_code != FINGERPRINT_STARTCODE)
        return FINGERPRINT_BADPACKET;
      break;
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
      packet->address[idx - 2] = byte;
      break;
    case 6:
      packet->type = byte;
      break;
    case 7:
      packet->length = (uint16_t)byte << 8;
      break;
    case 8:
      packet->length |= byte;
      break;
    default:
      packet->data[idx - 9] = byte;
      if ((idx - 8) == packet->length)
        return FINGERPRINT_OK;
      break;
    }
    idx++;
  }
  // Shouldn't get here so...
  return FINGERPRINT_BADPACKET;
}
```

Is what I'm doing at all possible or am I just doing it wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with NeoSWSerial and some help from AdaFruit. For those in the future:

1. Write the blank example sketch to the arduino
2. Go to device manager and switch the COM port that the arduino is connected to COM1 (Right click > Properties) - This applies even if you're using an FTDI breakout
3. Download and extract the [SFG Demo Software](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-optical-fingerprint-sensor/downloads)
4. Click Open Device and select COM1
5. Change the baud rate (lower left corner) to 19200 - anything else seems unreliable (from my testing)
6. Replace all instances of SoftwareSerial to NeoSWSerial in the .cpp and .h files as well as your sketch. Change the finger.begin(57600) to finger.begin(19200) in the example sketches and that's it

If it doesn't work go back to device manager and change the baud rate on the COM port to 57600
Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Why don't they have that library take a Stream object so it doesn't matter what sort of serial you use?  Seems like this is an unnecessary dependency.